# INSERT based on another columns value

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I want to update a column 'XYZ_RCVD' to 'Y' if there is a value in the row, if not i want to update column 'XYZ_RCVD' to 'N'. I started with this simple script that worked but I had to modify it for the 'N' case. How would i merge both of them into one?  I tried some IF-THEN-else but that didn't work too well with the INSERT statement.

Here is what i have so far.

```
UPDATE TEST_SURVEY
      SET XYZ_RCVD = 'Y'
      WHERE XYZ_NAME IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE TEST_SURVEY
          SET XYZ_RCVD = 'N'
          WHERE XYZ_NAME IS NULL;
```

The solution below by Habib worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `CASE WHEN` like:

```
UPDATE TEST_SURVEY
SET XYZ_RCVD = CASE WHEN XYZ_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
```

Comment: Sounds like a perfect solution, however  i need to compare it with XYZ_NAME column and then XYZ_RCVD will yield a "Y" or "N"

Comment: @user40720, missed that part, but you can just replace the field name in `CASE` and it should work. Modified the answer as well.

Comment: Perfect. It worked. One more final question, how can i incorporation an additional SET/CASE for other columns that would be compared by other reference column?

Comment: @user40720, You can specify multiple columns in `SET` like: `UPDATE TEST_SURVEY SET XYZ_RCVD = CASE WHEN XYZ_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END OTHERCOLUMN = SOMEOTHERVALUE`